# Get two random words from the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to generate two random words from  the same array.  Right now this script will pick one word but when I try and pick two words I run into a problem.  Here's the problem.  The user has a choice of picking multiple languages from checkboxes so when I make it two words the two words are in different languages (they come from different lists).  I would like to make sure that the two words chosen are from the same list.  How do I do this?

```
function word(){
var choice = [];
choice[0] = list0[Math.floor(Math.random()*list0.length)];
choice[1] = list1[Math.floor(Math.random()*list1.length)];
choice[2] = list2[Math.floor(Math.random()*list2.length)];
choice[3] = list3[Math.floor(Math.random()*list3.length)];

var final_words = [];
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
        final_words.push(choice[i]);
    }
}
var finalword = final_words[Math.floor(Math.random()*final_words.length)];
}
```

Comment: Its really hard to give an answer when we don't have an example list. Set up a demo so we don't have to guess on jsfiddle or something

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qbFq3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you meant?

```
list0 = ['compare', 'power', 'random', 'raw', 'nothing', 'practice'];
list1 = ['Comparar', 'energía', 'azar', 'crudo', 'nada', 'práctica'];
list2 = ['comparer', 'puissance', 'aléatoire', 'saveur', 'brute'];
list3 = ['比 ', '较 ', '随 ', '机 ', '的 ', '电 ', '源 ', '没 ', '有 ', '生 ', '实 ', '践 '];

// used to match the lists with the id's of the checkboxes (lanugages)
available_words = {
    c1: list0,
    c2: list1,
    c3: list2,
    c4: list3
};

function pickRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function getCheckedCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
    var checked_checkboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checked_checkboxes.push(checkboxes[i]);
        }
    }
    return checked_checkboxes;
}

function getRandomWords(lang_id, no_words) {
    words = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < no_words; i++) {
        do {
            rand_word = pickRandom(available_words[lang_id]);
        } while (words.indexOf(rand_word) >= 0);
        words.push(rand_word);
    }
    return words;
}

function word() {
    var words = [];
    var checked_checkboxes = getCheckedCheckboxes();
    if (checked_checkboxes.length != 0) {
        var rand_checkbox = pickRandom(checked_checkboxes);
        words = getRandomWords(rand_checkbox.id, 2);
    }
    document.getElementById('q').innerHTML = words.join(' ');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pMMB2/4/

Comment: As written choice[i] does not exist. Change line final_words.push(choice[i]) to final_words.push(random_list[i]) and remove var choice=[];

Comment: Sorry,, wrote this is a hurry in the train. Should do the trick now.

Comment: pefect except it uses all the lists even if the check boxes are unchecked